# Как в select записать function

Tags: javascript, html

Как в select(option) записать  функцию(func_2)?

```
<select>
    <option value="one">Святошинско-Броварская</option>
    <option value="func_2()">Оболонско-Теремковская</option> // вот тут функцию
    <option value="tree">Сырецко-Печерская</option>
</select>
```

Comment: а в итоге зачем это нужно?(что бы представлять картину в целом)

Comment: Функция должа выводить массив

Comment: То есть у каждой функции свой массив

Comment: что мешает указать массив в качестве значения? и выводить его при смене опции?

Answer (score 1):

```js
document.querySelector("select").addEventListener('change', function() {
  var handlers = {
    one: function() {},
    two: function() { console.log("called func_2 - выводить массив"); }
  };
  handlers[this.value] && handlers[this.value]();
});
```

```html
<select>
    <option value="one">Святошинско-Броварская</option>
    <option value="two">Оболонско-Теремковская</option>
    <option value="three">Сырецко-Печерская</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Может так пойдет(если честно не особо понятно, что надо вам):

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $("#mySelect [id='opt2']").val(func_2());
    console.log(  $("#mySelect [id='opt2']").val());
    
    function func_2(){
      return ["1", "2"];
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="mySelect">
    <option value="">Святошинско-Броварская</option>
    <option id="opt2" value="">Оболонско-Теремковская</option> // вот тут функцию
    <option value="">Сырецко-Печерская</option>
</select>
```